# Is there a way to test whether a target has native half-precision support in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, half-precision-float

Clang documentation says:

> _Float16 arithmetic will be performed using native half-precision support when available on the target (e.g. on ARMv8.2a); otherwise it will be performed at a higher precision (currently always float) and then truncated down to _Float16.

Is there a way to say I want to use `_Float16` only in the first case, and `float` otherwise, to avoid the truncation in the second case? I.e. something like

```
#if ???
using float_maybe_16 = _Float16;
#else
using float_maybe_16 = float;
#endif
```

Comment: "Is there a way to say I want to use _Float16 only in the first case, and float otherwise?" - Isn't the documentation you quoted saying that that's what you'll get by *default*??

Comment: @JesperJuhl No. The default is to truncate away extra precision when a real half-precision type is missing. The pseudocode as given would keep that precision if half-precision arithmetic is not available. It's a subtle distinction, so the OP should probably clarify whether that's the intent.

Comment: Have you looked at `__SIZEOF_FLOAT__`?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to avoid truncation in the second case.

Comment: @FTrias Going by https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html it doesn't seem to be relevant, it's just `sizeof(float)` whether there is half-precision support or not. Unless I misunderstand something?